How to calculate DAU, MAU based on daily clicks with SQL
DAU - daily active users, the number of users who use the product one or more times in a day (it doesn't matter if the user spent the whole day or made one click in the app - we count it as one user)
MAU - Monthly Active Users, the number of users who use the product one or more times per month.
SF - Sticky Factor. A metric calculated daily as DAU/MAU * 100%. Here we use MAUs for the previous 30 days, so the MAU boundaries shift with each date.
We have a table clicks with date, product and user.
INSERT INTO public.clicks (product, date, user_id)
VALUES  
(125,'2023-12-18',1378),
(1482,'2023-12-18',1722),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(1482,'2023-12-18',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-18',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-18',1722),
(125,'2023-12-18',475),
(125,'2023-12-18',475),
(125,'2023-12-18',475),
(125,'2023-12-18',475),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-18',704),
(129,'2023-12-18',715),
(129,'2023-12-18',715),
(129,'2023-12-18',704),
(129,'2023-12-18',704),
(129,'2023-12-18',927),
(129,'2023-12-18',927),
(129,'2023-12-18',927),
(129,'2023-12-18',704),
(129,'2023-12-18',927),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(125,'2023-12-18',475),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',149),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(125,'2023-12-18',1378),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(125,'2023-12-18',1378),
(129,'2023-12-18',1378),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-18',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',927),
(129,'2023-12-19',927),
(129,'2023-12-19',927),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',927),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',338),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(1482,'2023-12-19',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-19',1467),
(17,'2023-12-19',974),
(129,'2023-12-19',149),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(125,'2023-12-19',539),
(125,'2023-12-19',974),
(129,'2023-12-19',149),
(125,'2023-12-19',1190),
(129,'2023-12-19',704),
(125,'2023-12-19',539),
(150,'2023-12-19',338),
(129,'2023-12-19',338),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(129,'2023-12-19',338),
(150,'2023-12-19',338),
(129,'2023-12-19',338),
(125,'2023-12-19',1190),
(129,'2023-12-19',488),
(125,'2023-12-19',1190),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(150,'2023-12-19',559),
(150,'2023-12-19',1359),
(129,'2023-12-19',1359),
(129,'2023-12-19',559),
(150,'2023-12-19',559),
(129,'2023-12-19',1359),
(150,'2023-12-19',1359),
(129,'2023-12-19',1359),
(150,'2023-12-19',1359),
(150,'2023-12-19',1359),
(150,'2023-12-19',1359),
(129,'2023-12-19',1359),
(125,'2023-12-19',974),
(125,'2023-12-19',974),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',149),
(150,'2023-12-20',338),
(129,'2023-12-20',338),
(129,'2023-12-20',338),
(129,'2023-12-20',338),
(129,'2023-12-20',338),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(150,'2023-12-20',1359),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(150,'2023-12-20',1359),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',1359),
(150,'2023-12-20',1359),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(150,'2023-12-20',1359),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(129,'2023-12-20',1378),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(129,'2023-12-20',658),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(129,'2023-12-20',658),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(129,'2023-12-20',658),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(129,'2023-12-20',488),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1722),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467),
(17,'2023-12-20',1725),
(1482,'2023-12-20',1467);

And expected result is:
[![Result][2]][2]
DAU is easily calculated by COUNT(DISTINCT(user)). I've tried to find MAU using Window function and CTE (as in code snippet below), but with no success.
WITH RECURSIVE t(date) AS (
    SELECT 
        CURRENT_DATE as date
        ,c1.product AS cmd 
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT c1.user_id) as mau
    FROM public.clicks c1
    WHERE (c1.date BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE - interval '30 day' AND CURRENT_DATE) 
    GROUP BY 1, 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        (t.date - interval '1 day')::DATE date
        ,c2.product 
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT c2.user_id) as mau
    FROM t, public.clicks c2
    WHERE (c2.date BETWEEN t.date - interval '30 day' AND t.date) 
    GROUP BY 1, 2)
SELECT *
FROM t;

How to build a query to this table to calculate DAU, MAU and SF for each product and day?
ADD
PostgreSQL 16.0
There is a query, but it is too heavy, and takes much time to execute
WITH dau AS (
        SELECT 
            cl.product,
            cl.date,
        COUNT(DISTINCT cl.user_id) as dau
        FROM public.clicks cl
        GROUP BY 1, 2
        ORDER BY 1 DESC
     )
SELECT 
    date,
    product,
    dau,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ds.user_id)
        FROM public.clicks ds
        WHERE ds.date BETWEEN dau.date - 29 * interval '1 day' and dau.date
       ) as mau
FROM dau;


Please provide table definitions as CREATE TABLE script, and sample rows as INSERT script. No images. And always declare your Postgres version.

MAU for product0 for 03.11.2024=3? What if DAU for =0?

DISTINCT is a set quantifier, not a function... Simply write COUNT(DISTINCT c2.user) to make code clearer - for everyone.

The expected result has gone missing. A smaller sample would do the job for the purpose of this question. And you should upgrade to the latest point release of your major Postgres version (currently 16.4).

"for each product and day" - How are the two sets (days, products) defined exactly? Is there a table product that defines products of interest? A given time range that defines days? What about (product, date) combinations without any entries?
